# Convert Dictionary of similar Keys into List of Dictionaries (Updated)

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

All `keys` repeat, but for a new instance. All `keys` are prefixed with `id_<X>.`.

Based on this `prefix`, I want to split up this `dictionary` into a `list` of many `dictionaries`.

Importantly, I need these `keys` to maintain **order of occurrence**.

What is the most *Pythonic* way of doing this?

Update: What if some `keys` exist for a given `id_<X>.` but not for others?

All sub-`dictionaries` should propagate these same `key` names but with a blank `string` entry.

---

Dictionary (Updated):

```
my_dict = {'id_1.First Name': 'val', 'id_1.Middle Name': 'val', 'id_1.Second Name': 'val', 'id_2.First Name': 'val', 'id_2.Second Name': 'val', 'id_3.First Name': 'val', 'id_3.Second Name': 'val', 'id_3.Phone': 'val'}
```

Desired Output (Updated):

```
data = [{'First Name': 'val', 'Middle Name': 'val', 'Second Name': 'val', 'Phone': ''},
        {'First Name': 'val', 'Middle Name': '', 'Second Name': 'val', 'Phone': ''},
        {'First Name': 'val', 'Middle Name': '', 'Second Name': 'val', 'Phone': 'val'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below code

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'id_1.First Name': 'x', 'id_1.Middle Name': 'val', 'id_1.Second Name': 'val', 'id_2.First Name': 'y',
           'id_2.Second Name': 'val', 'id_3.First Name': 'z', 'id_3.Second Name': 'val', 'id_3.Phone': 'val'}
seen = set()
fields = set()
data = []
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    prefix, field_name = k.split('.')
    fields.add(field_name)
    if prefix not in seen:
        data.append({})
        seen.add(prefix)
    data[-1][field_name] = v
for entry in data:
    for field in fields:
        if entry.get(field) is None:
            entry[field] = ''

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
First Name Middle Name Second Name Phone
0          x         val         val      
1          y                     val      
2          z                     val   val
```

Comment: So I need to have all keys represented in all sub-dictionaries. E.g. `Middle Name` only appears in `id_1`, but I would like it to appear in all other sub-dictionaries, with a blank string value `''` (since it wasn't in them). My post shows an example before and after.

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 code was updated. Have a look.

Comment: Is it possible to retain a *"original order"*? I say this crudely, as each `dict` has their own `keys`.  E.g. Since `Phone` appears only in `id_3` and in last position, I would like `'Phone': ''` to appear in all other `dicts` at the end position.

Comment: order is not important in a dict (as far as I understand..)

Comment: My final goal is to convert the Dictionary into a Dataframe. So in this rare case, order would matter for my dictionaries.

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 You are wrong. It will be converted to a df just as you want.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll try. One moment

Comment: Just saw it working myself. Tysm. Note: I had used `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` instead, but your line is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I think about generators and comprehension notation when you say pythonic ;)

```
my_dict = {'id_1.First Name': 'val', 'id_1.Second Name': 'val', 'id_2.First Name': 'val', 'id_2.Second Name': 'val', 'id_3.First Name': 'val', 'id_3.Second Name': 'val'}
data = [{k1.split('.')[-1]:my_dict[k1],
          k2.split('.')[-1]:my_dict[k2]} for k1, k2 in zip(list(my_dict.keys())[0::2], list(my_dict.keys())[1::2])]
data
```

Comment: What if some `keys` exist for a given `id_<X>.`, but not for others? How can I have that work with your code?

Comment: I have appended example input and output code to original post.